# why is the nodejs event loop non-deterministic after the first run?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

Node.js [doc](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) says:

> The order in which the timers are executed will vary depending on the context in which they are called. If both are called from within the main module, then timing will be bound by the performance of the process (which can be impacted by other applications running on the machine).
>
> For example, if we run the following script which is not within an I/O cycle (i.e. the main module), the order in which the two timers are executed is non-deterministic, as it is bound by the performance of the process:
>
> ```
> // timeout_vs_immediate.js
> setTimeout(function timeout () {
>  console.log('timeout');
> },0);
>
> setImmediate(function immediate () {
>   console.log('immediate');
> });
>
> $ node timeout_vs_immediate.js
> timeout
> immediate
>
> $ node timeout_vs_immediate.js
> immediate
> timeout
> ```

From the same page I think I understand how the event loop works, but after this main run, why can the even loop not fulfill its job correctly ? What's so different there than within an I/O cycle ?

Answer (score 5):

As Node.js doc says:

> [setimmediate-vs-settimeout](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#setimmediate-vs-settimeout)
>   The order in which the timers are executed will vary depending on the context in which they are called. If both are called from within the main module, then timing will be bound by the performance of the process (which can be impacted by other applications running on the machine).
>   For example, if we run the following script which is not within an I/O cycle (i.e. the main module), the order in which the two timers are executed is non-deterministic, as it is bound by the performance of the process:

Why ?.

Every event in node.js is driven by `uv_run()` function of libuv. Partial Code

```
int uv_run(uv_loop_t* loop, uv_run_mode mode) {
  int timeout;
  int r;
  int ran_pending;

  r = uv__loop_alive(loop);
  if (!r)
    uv__update_time(loop);

  while (r != 0 && loop->stop_flag == 0) {
    uv__update_time(loop);
    uv__run_timers(loop);
    ran_pending = uv__run_pending(loop);
    uv__run_idle(loop);
    uv__run_prepare(loop);

    ......

    uv__io_poll(loop, timeout);
    uv__run_check(loop);
    uv__run_closing_handles(loop);
    ............
```

So As explained by the node.js Doc, we can match each Phase of the event loop in the code.

**Timer Phase** `uv__run_timers(loop);`

**I/O Callback** `ran_pending = uv__run_pending(loop);`

**idle/ prepare** `uv__run_idle(loop); uv__run_prepare(loop);`

**poll**  `uv__io_poll(loop, timeout);`

**check** `uv__run_check(loop);`

**close callbacks**  `uv__run_closing_handles(loop);`

#### More than phase

But if we see the code closely before the loop goes to timer phase, it calls 
`uv__update_time(loop);`  to initialize the loop time.

```
void uv_update_time(uv_loop_t* loop) {
   uv__update_time(loop);
}
```

What happens is `uv__update_time(loop)` calls an function `uv__hrtime`

```
UV_UNUSED(static void uv__update_time(uv_loop_t* loop)) {
  /* Use a fast time source if available.  We only need millisecond precision.
   */
  loop->time = uv__hrtime(UV_CLOCK_FAST) / 1000000;
}
```

This call to `uv__hrtime` is platform dependent and is cpu-time-consuming work as it makes system
call to [clock_gettime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime). It's is impacted by other application running on the machine.

```
#define NANOSEC ((uint64_t) 1e9)
uint64_t uv__hrtime(uv_clocktype_t type) {
  struct timespec ts;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
  return (((uint64_t) ts.tv_sec) * NANOSEC + ts.tv_nsec);
}
```

Once this is returned Timer phase is called in the event loop.

```
void uv__run_timers(uv_loop_t* loop) {
  ...
  for (;;) {
    ....
    handle = container_of(heap_node, uv_timer_t, heap_node);
    if (handle->timeout > loop->time)
      break;
      ....
    uv_timer_again(handle);
    handle->timer_cb(handle);
  }
}
```

The callback in the Timer phase is run if the current time of loop is greater than the timeout. 
One more important things to note is `setTimeout` when set to `0` is internally converted to `1`.
Also as the `hr_time` return time in Nanoseconds, this behaviour as shown by the `timeout_vs_immediate.js` becomes more explanatory now.

If the preparation before the first loop took more than `1ms` then the `Timer` Phase calls the callback associated with it. If it's is less than `1ms` Event-loop continues to next phase and runs the `setImmediate` callback in check phase of the loop and `setTimeout` in the
next tick of the loop.

Hopefully this clarifies the way around the non-deterministic behaviour of `setTimeout` and `setImmediate` when both are called from within the main module.